# What is the difference between ^(?!(xx+)\1+$) and ^(?!(xx+)\1+)$?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

What is the difference between `^(?!(xx+)\1+$)` and `^(?!(xx+)\1+)$`? Why does the former solve the "match a prime number of x" problem while the latter matches none?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^(?!(xx+)\1+)$` will not match anything but the emptry string asthere is nothing to match between anchors `^` and `$` (An empty string will satisfy negative lookahead).

`^(?!(xx+)\1+$)` can be rewritten as `^(?!(x{2,})\1+$)` and will match only prime number of `x`. As it is negating all matches with 2+ matches of `x` - repeated 1 or more times.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kY4nS8/2)

Comment: I wouuld rather say "non-prime number of `x`s", as the backreference is repeated as well (it might match 9 xs for example)